# mongodb-community start error 6 root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist

Tags: mongodb

I'm attempting to run MongoDB Community by copying and pasting files from a MongoDB backup. but everytime it returns "mongodb-community       error  6 root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist"

I've tried using 'sudo brew services start mongodb-community,' but it's not working. I also ran the 'chown' command on the '/mongodb' directory without success. Additionally, the 'rm -f /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock' command did not resolve the issue.

```
(base) ssss@sandris-MacBook-Pro mongodb % brew services restart mongodb-community

Stopping `mongodb-community`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-commu
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-commu
(base) ssss@sandris-MacBook-Pro mongodb % brew services list                   

Name                    Status   User File
jenkins                 none          
mongodb-community       error  6 root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
mongodb-community-shell none          
transmission-cli        none          
unbound                 none          
(base) ssss@sandris-MacBook-Pro mongodb %
```

Comment: "it's not working" can mean a lot of things, you should provide particular details, what you've tried and what exactly you expect and and what you see